# how to use open graph stories in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am looking to use open graph stories ( Facebook ) but when I look on the Facebook developers site, they only have tutorials for obj-c. As I am new to swift I can't translate the code, are there any tutorials out there or code translated that I could find? thanks for your help !

Comment: Basically you have two solutions: use the existing Objective-C code *in Swift* with a [bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), or you can learn the basics of Objective-C while learning Swift. You will need some knowledge of Objective-C later anyway (or at least to be familiar with it) because all existing Apple frameworks are in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that !